# Embedded C - string to char array

Tags: c, embedded

I've got string as follows 
`"123 132 244"` where that max value for an entry is 255

how can i convert that string to

unsigned char arr[3] = [123, ,132, ,244]

Comment: What is `[123, ,132, ,244]` supposed to stand for?

Comment: edited question

Comment: You can use [strtok](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) and delimit the string with white space and save it char array?

Comment: yes but the resulted array will be only one char in each element

Comment: Why is this tagged embedded? You don't have access to `strlen`, etc?

Comment: `unsigned char arr[3] = [123, ,132, ,244]` is not valid syntax and does not compile. Did you mean `unsigned char arr[3] = {123, 132, 244};`?

Comment: Or did you mean that you want odd elements of the array to be numbers and even elements to contain the ASCII space character `' '` (i.e. 32)?

Comment: `"123 132 244"` is simply a space delimited string.  If you do not have access to `string.h`, then parsing the original string into an array of `unsigned char` will need to be done by walking though one character at a time, and converting from string to char.

Comment: Embedded probably means no access to stdio.h, but access to string.h.

Answer (score 1):

1. Step 1 : valid the string's format (number - one space - number - one
   space ...)
2. Step 2 : Count the number of space
3. Step 3 : Allocate the final array
4. Step 4 : use strtok to have token + sscanf to convert the string to number
5. Step 5 : return array (+ array size ? It's always useful).

In which step do you have difficulty ?

Comment: The tag `embedded` may not be insignificant. It's possible `string.h` (etc.) is not available.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I'm not familiar with embedded C but a "manual" strotk and sscanf for int is still possible. You can even do the 2 step in one if you have to recode that part.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `"123 132 244"` is a string literal.  If you have access to string functions such as *[strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)* (defined in `strings.h`) then parse the string into three `char` values using *[strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)* and a string converter such as *[atoi()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)* or *[strtol()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm)*.  If you do not have access to `strings.h`, then the string to unsigned char conversion will need to be done another way.  Here is one example:

```
const char str[] = {"123 132 244"};

void convertStr(const char *string, unsigned int ucArr[3], size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int ucArray[3];
    convertStr(str, ucArray, sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]));

    return 0;
}

void convertStr(const char *string, unsigned int ucArr[3], size_t size)
{
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    int accum[3] = {0};//store numeric version of 3 alpha characters
    int ex = 0;//use in conversion of single digit value to place value.
    int acm = 0;//accumulate integer value of 3 successive integer values
                //stored in accum

        while(1)
        {
            if(isdigit(*string))
            {
                accum[i] = *string - '0';
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                //convert
                for(k=i-1;k>=0;k--)
                {
                    ex = pow(10, k);
                    acm += accum[i-k-1]*ex;
                }
                ucArr[j] = acm;
                j++;
                i=0;
            }
            acm = 0;
            if(*string == NULL) break;
            *string++;
        }
}
```

Comment: It's more likely that an embedded system doesn't have access to `pow` than to `string.h`. `pow` would mean that you have to load in some software floating point library which you don't want unless you actually have FPU. Using `strtoul` in a little while loop is probably the correct solution.

Comment: @Lundin - will edit...

Comment: No need since the question is closed and this may all get deleted by the Roomba bot, eventually.

Comment: @Lundin - Okay.  Thanks for the input anyway.  I do not do a lot of embedded, so don't know what most dev system provide for the smaller uPs.